# Scraping data parallel + batch processing

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, batch-processing

I am doing a task that requires scraping. I have a dataset with ids and for each id i need to scrape some new information. This dataset has around 4 million rows. Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import semanticscholar as sch
import time

# dataset with ids
df = pd.read_csv('paperIds-1975-2005-2015-2.tsv', sep='\t', names=["id"])

# columns that will be produced
cols = ['id', 'abstract', 'arxivId', 'authors', 
        'citationVelocity', 'citations', 
        'corpusId', 'doi', 'fieldsOfStudy', 
        'influentialCitationCount', 'is_open_access', 
        'is_publisher_licensed', 'paperId', 
        'references', 'title', 'topics', 
        'url', 'venue', 'year']

# a new dataframe that we will append the scraped results
new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)

# a counter so we know when every 100000 papers are scraped
c = 0      
i = 0
while i < df.shape[0]:
    try:
        paper = sch.paper(df.id[i], timeout=10) # scrape the paper
        new_df = new_df.append([df.id[i]]+paper, ignore_index=True) # append to the new dataframe
        new_df.to_csv('abstracts_impact.csv', index=False) # save it 
        if i % 100000 == 0: # to check how much we did
            print(c)
            c += 1
        i += 1
    except:
        time.sleep(60)
```

The problem is that the dataset is pretty big and this approach is not working. I left it working for 2 days and it scraped around 100000 ids, and then suddenly just froze and all the data that was saved was just empty rows.
I was thinking that the best solution would be to parallelize and batch processing. I never have done this before and I am not familiar with these concepts. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so first of all there is no data :( so I am just taking a sample ID from [semanticscholar](https://pypi.org/project/semanticscholar/) documents. Looking at your code, there I can see plenty of mistakes:

1. Don't always stick to `pd.DataFrame` for your work! Dataframe are great, but are also slow! You just need to get the ID from the `'paperIds-1975-2005-2015-2.tsv'` so you can either read the file using `file.readline()` or you can save the data into a list:

```py
data = pd.read_csv('paperIds-1975-2005-2015-2.tsv', sep='\t', names=["id"]).id.values
```

2. From the code flow, what I understand is you want to save the scraped data into a *single* CSV file, right? So, why are you appending the data and saving the file again and again? This makes the code like 100000s time slower!
3. I really don't understand the purpose of `time.sleep(60)` you have added. If there is some error, you should print and move on - why wait?
4. For checking the progress, you can use the `tqdm` [library](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-how-to-make-a-terminal-progress-bar-using-tqdm/) which shows a nice progress bar for your code!

Taking these into consideration, I have modified your code as follows:

```py
import pandas as pd
import semanticscholar as sch
from tqdm import tqdm as TQ # for progree-bar

data = ['10.1093/mind/lix.236.433', '10.1093/mind/lix.236.433'] # using list or np.ndarray looks more logical!
print(data)
>> ['10.1093/mind/lix.236.433', '10.1093/mind/lix.236.433']
```

Once you have done this, you can now go and scrape the data. Okay, before that `pandas DataFrame` is basically a dictionary with advanced features. So, for our purpose, we will first add all the information to the dictionary and then create the dataframe. I personally prefer this process - gives me more control, if there are any changes need to be done.

```py
cols = ['id', 'abstract', 'arxivId', 'authors', 'citationVelocity', 'citations',
    'corpusId', 'doi', 'fieldsOfStudy', 'influentialCitationCount', 'is_open_access',
    'is_publisher_licensed', 'paperId', 'references', 'title', 'topics', 'url', 'venue', 'year']

outputData = dict((k, []) for k in cols)

print(outputData)
{'id': [],
 'abstract': [],
 'arxivId': [],
 'authors': [],
 'citationVelocity': [],
 'citations': [],
 'corpusId': [],
 'doi': [],
 'fieldsOfStudy': [],
 'influentialCitationCount': [],
 'is_open_access': [],
 'is_publisher_licensed': [],
 'paperId': [],
 'references': [],
 'title': [],
 'topics': [],
 'url': [],
 'venue': [],
 'year': []}
```

Now you can simply fetch the data and save it into your dataframe as below:

```py
for _paperID in TQ(data):
    paper = sch.paper(_paperID, timeout = 10) # scrape the paper
    for key in cols:
        try:
            outputData[key].append(paper.get(key))
        except KeyError:
            outputData[key].append(None) # if there is no data, append none
            print(f"{key} not Found for {_paperID}")

pd.DataFrame(outputData).to_csv('output_file_name.csv', index = False)
```

This is the output that I have obtained:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Now to answer some of your questions: I wanted to wait if there is an error because my internet connection is not good and sometimes it gets disconnected, I was saving the data every time because I didn't know when the code will stop and I wanted at least to save something. I wanted to use multithreading for this task in order to get the job done in a faster way.

Comment: Oh okay, for the internet connection problem you can keep a track of the papers that were not downloaded - then you can retry them later. For saving the data - as long as your program is running, your variables are stored in memory.

Comment: Another thing, parallel processing create problem in python due to GIL, and on windows based system I had an issue running the program previously. So I will suggest using an alternative. For instance, for every x-records create a new file and save.